# glm output in R: analysis without coefficients

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression

Generally, coefficients and their p values are focused upon while assessing the regression output. However, there are other things mentioned. How can we analyze the output of glm without the coefficients:

```
> summary(mod)

Call:
glm(formula = outvar ~ ., family = binomial, data = mydf)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3537  -0.8172  -0.6462   1.2131   2.2757  

Coefficients:
....
....


(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 8973.8  on 7760  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 8526.6  on 7752  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8544.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Can I use the glm output shown above to understand my regression without coefficients being available?

Comment: This seems highly artificial: it is difficult to conceive of a circumstance where this is the only information you would have. What actual problem are you trying to address?

Comment: I am trying to understand this part of glm output, especially Deviance Residuals, Null and Residual deviance.

Comment: Then rather than asking us to guess that is your interest, why not ask that directly? And why hasn't a [search of our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=deviance+residual) been satisfactory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the covariates explain the response properly, they should lower deviance statistically significantly. Deviance analysis can be performed using `anova()`. In the output table, `Null Deviance` is where only the intercept is added to fit while `Residual Deviance` is from the fitted model. The difference follows the chi-squared distribution and, if it is statistically significant, the fitted model can be considered to improve model fit - it can be simply done using `anova()` as shown below.

Here deviance analysis can be performed as the null and fitted models are nested - only some covariates are added to the null model. If a non-nested model (eg time series model) is to be compared, an information criterion can be used. AIC and BIC are popular and AIC is shown by default.

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts)
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())
glm.reduced <- glm(counts ~ 1, family = poisson())

glm.D93
#Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())

#Coefficients:
#  (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#    3.045e+00   -4.543e-01   -2.930e-01    1.338e-15    1.421e-15  

#Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#Null Deviance:     10.58 
#Residual Deviance: 5.129   AIC: 56.76

anova(glm.reduced, glm.D93, test = "Chisq")
#Analysis of Deviance Table

#Model 1: counts ~ 1
#Model 2: counts ~ outcome + treatment
#Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
#1         8    10.5814                     
#2         4     5.1291  4   5.4523    0.244
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any quantitative assessment of the degree of improvement (like effect size), eg the deviance is reducing by only 5% in my example ((8973-8526)/8973) and 51% in yours ((10.58-5.129)/10.58).

Comment: Let say GLM is fit with random samples repetitively - 100 fits using 100 random samples. The null hypothesis is the NULL model (no covariate) is correct (or covariates has no explanatory power). Roughly speaking, there are 24 out of 100 chances that the null hypothesis is rejected incorrectly in my example (`1- pchisq(5.4523, df=4) #[1] 0.2439543`). On the other hand, there's no case in your example (`1 - pchisq((8973.8 - 8526.6), df = (7760 - 7752)) #[1] 0`) and overall the covariates are good. You may check this using `anova()` as well.

Comment: I agree that the p value is very significant in my example but can I say for my example that 'Different predictors improved the Deviance by only 5%'? Also is this fractional change in Deviance similar to R-squared in terms of interpretation?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is possible to say the deviance drops by 5% but I'm not sure if it gives good information. In general, the more decrease, the better model fit but it cannot be specific without considering its distributional property. The p-value does so. 2. Less deviance means better fit and you may link it to R-squared value of linear regression.

Comment: Can we determine confidence interval of this fractional change in deviance ((8973-8526)/8973) ?